# android volley post request with body

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I have an api POST method when I pass parameters in body using post man its working fine but in android using volley I tried this

```
StringRequest makeComment = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, respond, errorRespond) {

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params2.put("fullname", "s");
                params2.put("content", "s");
                params2.put("post_id", "149603");
                return new JSONObject(params2).toString().getBytes();
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }

        };
```

and tried this

```
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("fullname", "s");
                params.put("content", "s");
                params.put("post_id", "149603");

                return params;
            }
```

but not work it show 404 error in log and

> com.android.volley.ServerError

Comment: Your code is fine, this is a problem of your api

Comment: api work when try from Postman